# Combine objective-c enum in swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, ios8

I am using the wahoo fitness API (which is in objective-c) in my swift app.
I am trying to combine bitwise multiple items from an enum which is not an NS_ENUM. It is defined as:

```
typedef enum
{
    /** Specifies non-existent sensor. */
    WF_SENSORTYPE_NONE                           = 0,
    /** Specifies the bike power sensor. */
    WF_SENSORTYPE_BIKE_POWER                     = 0x00000001,
    /** Specifies the bike speed sensor. */
    WF_SENSORTYPE_BIKE_SPEED                     = 0x00000002,
    /** Specifies the bike cadence sensor. */
    WF_SENSORTYPE_BIKE_CADENCE                   = 0x00000004,

    ...

} WFSensorType_t;
```

The following resulted in: `'WFSensorType_t' is not convertible to 'Bool'`

```
let sensorType = WF_SENSORTYPE_HEARTRATE | WF_SENSORTYPE_BIKE_SPEED | WF_SENSORTYPE_BIKE_CADENCE // WFSensorType_t
```

The tricky part is that `sensorType` needs to be passed to another wahoo API object which accepts a `WFSensorType_t` so I can't wrap the enum into something else otherwise it won't be able to pass it back to the existing API.

Any idea?

Comment: It shouldn't be `NS_ENUM` but should be `NS_OPTIONS`: `typedef NS_OPTIONS(NSInteger, WFSensorType_t) { ... };`

Answer (score 5):

You can try:

```
let sensorType = WF_SENSORTYPE_HEARTRATE.value | WF_SENSORTYPE_BIKE_SPEED.value | WF_SENSORTYPE_BIKE_CADENCE.value
```

However `sensorType` will be inferred by Swift as type `UInt8`. You cannot declare it as  `WFSensorType_t`

Comment: I got the same problem trying to reference an objective-c enum from swift, and getting the error "'MyEnum.Type' does not have a member named 'MyEnumValue1'".  This solved my problem also, thank you!